# Why does the "blender-tpaw" package exist?

Tags: package-management, blender

Looking for Blender in the software store and I see "blender-tpaw" package

[image]

What does this package do and how is it separate from blender?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you maybe know, Ubuntu recently introduced a package format called [Snaps](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy), in addition to the familiar Deb format. "tpaw" is the nickname or handle of Thomas CaseyWilcox, who [created a snap package of Blender](https://plus.google.com/+ZackCasey/posts/L2rTJyqsrM1). So basically, "blender-tpaw" is Blender in another wrapping.

Comment: omg ... "blender-h1ck3r-thats-me-i-love-you-thank-you-all" :-) Package name is really bad place for packager's signature. All users must be mistaken with that.

Answer (score 3):

For no good reason. It is still there in 2020, not even up to date with the latest Blender version, when there is an official snap from the Blender Foundation. It should be deleted to avoid confusion.